# React router v6, Remove History

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there a way to remove history in react-router v6, I'm creating a web app, when the user reaches to homepage and presses back it should eventually exit the app. but as of now, it's going back if history exists. if react-router doesn't have this feature is there an alternative way to overcome this issue?

Comment: are you running it in Electron? If not, don't mess with the browser history: if the user changes pages, or takes a content-swapping action, that should be have a history state they can go back/forward from/to, and if they hit "back" after landing on a page, they should go back to _where they were before_, not "trigger an app exit".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that's true i don't want to mess with the history and stumble on some other issue, no it's not electron, it's PWA. as of now when the user reaches back to the home page im using `window.history.pushState(null, null, "/");` to force there is no back.

Comment: I'd strongly advise removing that history wipe: as long as someone's in a browser, their back button should take them back to where they were before navigating to where they are now. There's already an exit button: you close the tab.

Answer (score 2):

I have just done a PWA app like you and the way I solved this is that I always set option {replace: true} whenever it went forward or backward.

Ex:
`navigate(/${SCREEN_1}, { replace: true })`
or
`navigate(-1, { replace: true })`

So when user click on button "Next"/"Back" on the browser, there were only the first blank page of the browser (where before I open my URL) and the current page.

My app only have 6 screens.
I'm not sure whether this way will be useful for you or not, but for me it did.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question excatly.
But below code maybe helpful to go back to previous page.

```js
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate()
   const goBack = () => {
      navigate(-1)
}

return (
   <>
      <button onClick={goBack}>Back</button>
   </>
)
}
```